# 32 vs 64-bit DLL causing inconsistent compiling bugs between Visual Studio and TFS Express Build

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfsbuild

I'm brand new to TFS Express, but we badly need a build server with continuous integration, so I've been experimenting at work and learning how to set things up.

Undoubtedly, we need to use the 32-bit version of the Oracle.DataAccess DLL.  This compiles fine in visual studio.

However, TFS Express will not build with the 32-bit version - it only works with the 64-bit version.

I'm completely in the dark - can anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the TFS build definition change the MSBuild platform from "Auto" to "X86". It appears in the "3. Advanced" group of the Process tab for the Default Template.